# Scifi comic book. Female character has stripe on her nose. Picked up by aliens

Tags: story-identification, comics

The only thing I remember in the first book is a human girl with a white stripe on her nose, who was found by aliens on some random planet. They picked her up and took her with them. She is the only human that they know of.

She was in her teens, I don't recall her name. The marks on her nose were horizontal and just a white line. She lived in a crashed spaceship. There was a variety of aliens, like Star Wars. I'm pretty sure it wasn't Marvel or DC, and it was all in color. It was aimed at teens, I guess in the early 2000s. I know there are at least 2 books, maybe more.

Comment: If I saw the cover I would recognize it.

Comment: I'm sure you can do better than this. Have a look at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if the checklist jog your memory.

Comment: How old is the girl? What is her name? Are the marks only on her nose? Do they run up and down her nose or across? Are the marks big or small? Why was she on a random planet? What did the aliens look like? What kind of comic was it (Marvel, DC, something else)? Was it in black and white or colour? Was it aimed at adults or children? When did you read it?

Comment: She was in her teens don't recall her name the marks on her nose were horizontal and just a white line. she lived in a crashed spaceship, there were a variety of aliens like star wars, i gritty shore it wasn't Marvel or DC, and it was all in color, it was aimed at teen i guess early 2000. I know there is at least 2 books, maybe more.

Comment: Would you mind [edit]ing with that information? :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description it could be the french comic book series "[Sillage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_(comics))" known as "Wake" in the English version.

[image: Wake Volume 1 cover]

[image: Navïs / Navee]

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if it explained how the comics match the description.